# Shiny filter update doesnt show all modalities of variables

Tags: r, shiny

i'm trying yo built a dynamic app with can filter a datatable, whatr I want is when I choose a modality for my first varible my next filters will be updated and purpose me only modalities corresponding to my first filter and the same for the third filter 
I began by a reactive app but it not seems to works cause i have to always keep the "all" choice to show the other modalities and remove it after that ...is it possible to do that ?
So I decided to add an action button but not seems to work well with my update inputs

How can i fix it ? Thanks

An example of my app :

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = T, choices = c("All", LETTERS)),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = T, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)))),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = T, choices = c("All", letters)),
                 actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
                 p(class = 'text-center', downloadButton('dl', 'Download Data'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # Data
    df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
                 letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

    df1 <- df

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }

    input$goButton

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)

    datatable(df1)

  })

  output$dl <- downloadHandler('mydata.csv', content = function(file) {

    # Data
    df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
                 letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

    df1 <- df

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }


    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)

    datatable(df1)

    write.csv(df1, file)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Not sure what you want : your filters are updated as expected

Comment: Choose A in first filter then try to choose the 2 modalities in the second filter, i couldn't fix it i need to add "all" for choosing the two modalities. When I choose 1, i cant choose 27 ...

Comment: So just move your `updateSelectInput`s after the first filter and before the 2 other ones so df1 will still contain all modalities. But adding filters is a AND

Comment: moving updateSelctInputs after first filter is done but i didn't get your second advice ?ty

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: No i dont get what I want nothing change can you modify m'y example thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I select A and B in `Filter1`, the dataset is subset for `LETTERS` with `A` and `B`. The options in `Filter2` are `1,2,27,28` and `Filter3` are `A1, B2, A27, B28`. When I select `1` in `Filter2`, the option in `Filter3`is `A1` and when `2` is also selected in `Filter2`, `Filter3` is updated with `A1` and `A27` as options. You do not have an `All` option for `Filter2` and `Filter3`.  Is this what you are expecting?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", LETTERS)),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)))),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", letters))    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # Data
    df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
                 letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

    df1 <- df

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)



    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    datatable(df1)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code does not include the action button.

Comment: Thanks yes this IS it for functionnality just i want to have also thé "all" choice un the filters

Comment: pls, do you know how to remove first column of DT::DataTable which numbered rows ?

Comment: Include `rownames = FALSE` in your `datatable` function. `datatable(df1,rownames = FALSE)`

Comment: Very much useful, 2 days has been spent to find the similar solution, Just curious to know incase we don't want to show the table and hence wanted to use this functionality for updating filter values only, how can we achieve the same?